# Start the DC VM on a windows 2008 R2 cluster that need the DC

Tags: active-directory, cluster-computing, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, san

We herited the following architecture :

- 2 physicals server Windows 2008 R2
- a SAN

The 2 server are clustered and use a common LUN that contains all our production Hyperv VM. The primary domain controller is as well an hyperv VM.

Our problem is the following: Power stops during a while. When starting back the 2 HW machines, the cluster node can't mount because the Active directory ID can't be found (which is normal, as the VM is not started).

Here is the error message : *Cluster network name resource 'xxxx' cannot be brought online, Unable to get Computer Object using GUID*

Thus, if the cluster node can't start, impossible to access to the LUN.

And we are unable to find a DC single save.

Is there a way to force cluster to start without GUID ?

thanks a million in advance :(

PS: IBM recent hw for the 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't messed with hardware Cluster servers for a while, but it used to be best practice to have cluster nodes DCs in thier own domain, if it where likely, that they could start without being able to contact a DC for exactly the reason you stated.